# Do not showing my list on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I create simple recyclerView on main layout this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.safarayaneh.recycletest.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and then Create Adapter for it:

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyHolder> {

    private List<User> users;
    public RecycleAdapter(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
        MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = users.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(user.getName());
        holder.lName.setText(user.getlName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView lName;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            lName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvfamily);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Activity class:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            users.add(new User("pedro " + i, "ggg " + i));
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        RecycleAdapter adapter = new RecycleAdapter(users);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and my pojo User class:

```
    public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String lName;

    public User(String name, String lName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
}
```

but I don't know Why My simple list doen't appear on my recycler view?
I create before and everything was good but now I don't know why I can not!!!
exactly where is my mistake??

Comment: add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: recyclerview doen not need to notifyDatasetChanged(). you sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just update this on your RecycleAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}
```

Comment: it is work .thank you. but in list view i've not never use of ItemCount and everything was good.

Comment: For recycleView you have to add this. RecycleView create getItemCount() number of items. But don't forget to mark right answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this  change Your **`getItemCount`**

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != users ? users.size() : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below line also: (after recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager))

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

also in your adapter class :

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != this.users ? this.users.size() : 0);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

the count of recyclerView's item is from the the method getItemCount(),so you need to return the size.

```
public int getItemCount(){return users.size();}
```